# Google Maps - how to update markers / positions to existing map using ajax/PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a working Google Map on my site using Google Maps API v3.
The map is loaded on pageload and applied with multiple markers/positions from an array of coordinates.

Now, what I want to do is to dynamically update the markers/positions with a new array of coordinates with an ajax call.

Here is an example of my markup:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div> 


<script type="text/javascript">  
var LocationData = <?php echo $coordsarray; ?>;


function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      draggable: true
    } );

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i in LocationData)
    {
        var p = LocationData[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
        bounds.extend(latlng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: p[2]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.title);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


//Ajax call
var interval = 5000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
function doAjax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/codes/LiveVisitsStats/postlivecounter.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function (data) {
            var arr = data.split('|');
                    jQuery('#counterint').html(arr[0]);
                    jQuery('#extrainfoscounter').html(arr[1]);                           


            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
</script>
```

So what I now need to do is to send an array of coordinated via the Ajax call and on success update the existing Google Map with new coordinates.
I have tried to find a documentation of this but no luck..
If someone knows a good way to do this please help.

Comment: What does your data look like?  Do you have unique identifiers for the markers or are you going to remove all of them and create new ones on every cycle?

Comment: I´m just going to firstly remove all markers then create new ones from ajax array.

Comment: The array itself is like this example:
var coordinatesarray = [
  [141.274856, -53.890542, "Title description 1"],
  [121.274856, -32.890542, "Title description 2"],
  [131.274856, -23.890542, "Title description 3"],
  [159.274856, -13.890542, "Title description 4"],
  [251.274856, -83.890542, "Title description 5"]
];

Answer (score 0):

I ended up choosing a completely different approach. Here is the code I used, which works

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    var locations = {}; //A repository for markers (and the data from which they were contructed).

    //initial dataset for markers
    var locs = {
        1: {
            info: '11111. Some random info here',
            lat: -37.8139,
            lng: 144.9634
        },
        2: {
            info: '22222. Some random info here',
            lat: 46.0553,
            lng: 14.5144
        },
        3: {
            info: '33333. Some random info here',
            lat: -33.7333,
            lng: 151.0833
        },
        4: {
            info: '44444. Some random info here',
            lat: 27.9798,
            lng: -81.731
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 8,
        minZoom: 1,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    function setMarkers(locObj) {
        jQuery.each(locObj, function (key, loc) {
            if (!locations[key] && loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
                //Marker has not yet been made (and there's enough data to create one).

                //Create marker
                loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
                    map: map
                });

                //Attach click listener to marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(loc.marker, 'click', (function (key) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[key].info);
                        infowindow.open(map, locations[key].marker);
                    }
                })(key));

                //Remember loc in the `locations` so its info can be displayed and so its marker can be deleted.
                locations[key] = loc;
            } else if (locations[key] && loc.remove) {
                //Remove marker from map
                if (locations[key].marker) {
                    locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
                }
                //Remove element from `locations`
                delete locations[key];
            } else if (locations[key]) {
                //Update the previous data object with the latest data.
                jQuery.extend(locations[key], loc);
                if (loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
                    //Update marker position (maybe not necessary but doesn't hurt).
                    locations[key].marker.setPosition(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng));
                }
                //locations[key].info looks after itself.
            }
        });
    }




    setMarkers(locs); //Create markers from the initial dataset served with the document.
    //ajaxObj.get(); //Start the get cycle.

    // *******************



//Ajax code
var interval = 5000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
function doAjax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/codes/LiveVisitsStats/postlivecounter.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function (data) {
            var arr = data.split('|');
                    jQuery('#counterint').html(arr[0]);
                    jQuery('#extrainfoscounter').html(arr[1]);   
                    jQuery('#testdiv').html(arr[2]);         



//test: simulated ajax
var testLocs = {
        1: {
            info: '1. New Random info and new position',
            lat: -37,
            lng: 124.9634
        },
        2: {
            lat: 70,
            lng: 14.5144
        },
        3: {
            info: '3. New Random info'
        },
        4: {
            remove: true
        },
        5: {
            info: '55555. Added',
            lat: -37,
            lng: 0
        }
    };
setMarkers(testLocs);                   



            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);

</script>
```